# Firebase functions how can I listen for a different child 1 time for onWrite when triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

How can I listen to the child under a different node each time the Firebase functions onWrite is triggered

this child  =  {const saatt = (context.database
.ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/2021/1saat').once('value')).val();}

```
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/realtime/control')
    .onWrite((Change,context) =>{
        var oldDeger = Change.before.val();
        var newDeger = Change.after.val();
        
        
    
        if (newDeger > oldDeger){
          const saatt = (context.database
            .ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/2021/1saat').once('value')).val();
            if (saatt === 0){
                database.ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/realtime/ufuk').set('tamm');
    
            }
        
        }
       
    });
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your database structure and he explain on which node you want to trigger the function

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the section dedicated to [path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_instance_and_path) in the documentation of  Cloud Functions for the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wildcards to match multiple paths. I can't really understand your current path but let's put it this way:

```
//functions.database.ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/realtime/control')

functions.database.ref('kullanicilar/{thisId}/marina1/realtime/control')
```

Now your function will trigger on all paths that match his pattern. I above example value of thisId could be anything. Similarly you can add more wildcards.

Comment: onwrite is working properly it is triggering I want to listen to the saat1 child

Comment: @ufuksipor please share a screenshot of database. And by listen do you mean read value once? Because you should not use realtimr listeners in Cloud functions

Comment: If the condition is met, I want to read 1saat child 1 time.

Comment: const saatt = (context.database
            .ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/2021/1saat').once('value')).val();
            if (saatt === 0){
                database.ref('kullanicilar/1111/marina1/realtime/ufuk').set('tamm');
    
            }